# Dual core i7-3540M 3.0 GHz vs Quad corei7-3632QM 2.2 GHz

Tags: parallel-processing, multicore, gpu

I intend to buy a laptop to study parallel computing with GPU and multicore CPU. I don't know which is the better one between a Dual core i7-3540M 3.0 GHz and a Quad core i7-3632QM 2.2 GHz. Both of 2 latops has a Nvidia GT 650 graphic card. As far as i know, in GPU computing there is just one core of CPU to be used. So may be the Dual Core with higher clock speed make sense with better performance computing ? Do anyone please give me any suggestion? I really appreciate any reply. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Quad core means twice as many cores as dual. This means it is able to run more applications at once. The i7 3636QM also has a larger L3 Cache meaning more data can be stored for quick access. Therefore the quad core processor seems to be better for parallel computing; even though it has a lower clock speed.

When you have a single task that needs to be done right away, multiple cores can help you by breaking the task into smaller chunks, working on each chunk in parallel, and thus you'll get your work done quicker. In lower end tasks you would probably see a higher clock speed in a dual core work better; however in more complex tasks a quad core processor with a lower clock speed is still likely to perform better. With scientific and engineering tasks(presuming these are the tasks you are expecting to do) Quad would always triumph.

Comment: Yeah, studying parallel computing on a dual core machine is slightly limiting.

Comment: As far as i know, in GPU computing there is just one core of CPU to be used. So may be the Dual Core with higher clock speed make sense with better performance computing ?

Comment: Updated post to meet needs of second question.